# Stopping the Unity global menu from hijacking the menubar from my app

Tags: unity, c++

I'm developing an application for Ubuntu that (ab)uses the Gtk::MenuBar class to create a custom widget. It works fine on Gnome-Shell, but on Unity the widget gets hidden. I know I can disable the appmenu when I run the application using UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 but I want to disable it permanently in my app from the C++ code.

Is there a way to set a property on the widget so that the appmenu indicator will ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest possibility is already in your answer:

Your application owns its environment block. Do a call to `setenv` in your `main()` before you initialize gtk.

`man setenv` tells the whole story.
Also if there is the faintest possibility that you launch applications that *should* use the appmenu, `unsetenv` would come in handy.